# Modified Count when updating a entity with MongoRepository

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I am using Spring Data MongoDB Repository to connect to my mongo database.

I want to update a document in a collection by passing the criteria and specific fields to update.

I do that by setting the entity object directly with the fields to update along with _id field which would be used as criteria.

This is the code I am using,

```
Employee updatedEmployee=employeeRepository.save(employeeToUpdate);
```

When I used the save method, I see I do not get any return status , whether the update was successful or not.

I do not want to  make another query to mongodb to fetch the document and compare it with my updated document to validate the changes?

Is there a way with repository or should I use MongoTemplate for this specific usecase alone.